# jquery - execute function if parent element is shown - what is the right syntax

Tags: jquery

What I want to achieve is

1)  if '.box' is clicked -> show '.box-slides' and hide siblings;

2) .slidesjs on the '#slides01' element is only executed when '.box-slides' is shown.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
</div>
<div>
    <div class="box-slides" style="display:none">   
     <div class="container">
      <div id="slides01">
          <img src="assets/img/01.jpg">
          <img src="assets/img/02.jpg">
          <img src="assets/img/03.jpg">
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="sibling01">
    </div>
    <div class="sibling02">
    </div>
    <div class="sibling03">
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $('.box').click(function(){
   $('.box-slides').show().siblings().hide();     
   $('#slides01').slidesjs({       
      width: 700,
      height: 500,
      navigation: false
  });

});
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: I'm new in jQuery and wanted to make sure that this syntax is correct. It actually works as expected, however I get the error in a console "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.hide()')" but I'm aware this might be related to something different in my .js file.

Comment: I think that is unrelated, most likely you are trying to hide a element but you meant to hide a jQuery object. Use `$(this).hide()` to cast it to a jQuery object first. Rest of it looks good to me.